# How do I prevent Visual Studio Code from opening with previously-opened files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've noticed that, despite always closing it before I quit, despite opening other files as well, Visual Studio Code will always re-open a particular file when I launch the app. This is still the case after upgrading to the latest version - 0.7.0 at the time of writing.

Is there a setting I'm missing, or something that needs to be cleared out / blown away?

I'm running on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been fixed for the next release and only shows up when you work in file mode and not folder mode (that is when you are not actually opening a full folder inside VS Code).

To workaround this, use the `-n` option when you run VS Code. `-n` will force to open VS Code empty without any file or folder opened.

Comment: Thanks,  I was hoping for a simple answer.